# Cross join within a group in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to develop a T-SQL in SQL server 2012 or above, which will allow me to find all combinations of records within a group for two columns.

Given the following data:

Col1  Col2

3   2 

3   5

3   6

7   1

7   9

. .

. .

. .more groups

How can I get the desired results as following:

Col1  Col2

2 2

2 3

2 5

2 6

3 3

3 2

3 5

3 6

5 5

5 2

5 3

5 6

6 6

6 2

6 3

6 5

1 1

1 7

1 9

7 7

7 1

7 9

9 1

9 7

9 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure that there is nicer way:

```
create table #temp
(
 col1 INT,
 col2 INT
);


INSERT INTO #temp VALUES (3,2),(3,5),(3,6),(7,1),(7,9)


SELECT a.col1, b.col1
FROM (
select col1,  dense_rank() over (order by col1) dr from #temp
UNION
select col2,  dense_rank() over (order by col1) dr from #temp
) a
JOIN (
select col1,  dense_rank() over (order by col1) dr from #temp
UNION
select col2,  dense_rank() over (order by col1) dr from #temp
) b
ON a.dr = b.dr
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  But this will return full cross join, I want to have cross join result only within each group, line start with 3, line start with 7 and so on...

Comment: then provide exact example. The values you have + the result

Comment: exact example is in my post, value + result are in Given following data:  +  Desired results sections

Comment: then does it mean that in COL2 for group of 5 there supposed to be 5,2,3,6 instead of yours one 5,2,5,6? You have 2x5 there. And for the group of 6 there supposed to be the same? You have 2x6 there

Comment: I have modified desired results, it was wrong on 5s, and 6s.

Comment: check it. Next time provide scripts to populate test data

Answer (score 0):

What about

1. a select of the two columns
2. then a sort by of column one, then column two
3. then a find/hide duplicate query of the above results?

Should be do-able in one go at it with SQL...